# 'select file' dialog is always shown at an incorrect position

Tags: 11.10, dialog

For some reason the 'select file' dialog is always shown at an incorrect position - it is always shifted to the right bottom corner. So, the 'Save' or 'Open' buttons are  not showing and it is always necessary either to resize the dialog or maximize it.

The problem has began to occur after upgrading to ubuntu 11.10.
The snapshot below demonstrates the issue.

How I can fix it?

[image: popup dialog running off-screen]

Answer (score 2):

That is just windows placement.

Place your mouse cursor on the top bar of the file manager> left click and hold, drag the window back onto the screen. Temp fix.

You may modify your /apps/nautilus/preferences/navigation_window_saved_geometry

Using gconf-editor or dconf-editor navigate to /apps/nautilus/preferences/navigation_window_saved_geometry

The entry should be something like this "1268x683+219+78"

Save and exit.